# Move SKSpriteNode to a specific tile on SKTileMapNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

For simplicity, let's say I have an SKSpriteNode and an SKTileMapNode like so

```
var background = childNode(withName: "Background") as! SKTileMapNode
var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
```

I want to move player to the row position 5 and column position 8 in background, whats the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started, you could retrieve the position of the specified tile and create a move action to run on the player node.

```
let destination = background.centerOfTile(atColumn: 8, row: 5)
let action = SKAction.move(to: destination, duration: 5)

player.run(action)
```

Then you might look at `UITapGestureRecognizer` so the player can move to where you tap on the map.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you